Analyzing the following current mirror
I came across the circuits below in one of the videos on the YouTube channel All Electronics. It was sketched on the whiteboard.

YouTube Video: THD - Total Harmonic Distortion

I have tried to simulate and analyze the circuit, but I am unsure of my results.
From the DC sweep analysis on V1, it looks like a current mirror.
If so, what is the purpose of Q2? What determines the current in the above circuit?
I would appreciate it if anyone could explain the circuit and help analyze it.


It is not really a "current mirror" ... https://i.sstatic.net/VCRzbUyt.png

Hi Antonio51,
I think so, and It looks like a current mirror. Do you have any suggestions?

@Isay R1 means you will need a product-log function (LambertW) to solve for Iout itself. Also, Q2 just eliminates the Early effect of Q3 while also providing a substantial part of the Iout current. What do you already understand about this circuit?
